# Variation of max path sum problem using more directions

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I don't know how to approach this question.

We're given an N*N grid listing the costs to get from location a to location b.

Each row in the grid tells us the cost of getting from location to location (each location corresponds to a row in the costs array). (We say that location a is bigger than location b if row a appears after row b in the costs array. The index of every row is a location). We may choose to start from any given location, and visit every location exactly once. At every location p that we visit, we must have already visited all locations less than p, or no locations less than p.

- costs[a][b] gives us the cost to move from location a to location b.
- costs[a][b] is not necessarily the same as costs[b][a].
- costs[a][a] = 0 for every index a (diagonals in the costs array are always 0).

Our task is to find the maximum-sum cost of a valid path.

If the costs array is:

```
[[0, 9, 1],
 [5, 0, 2],
 [4, 6, 0]]
```

The max cost consequently will be 13 as the most expensive valid path is starting at location 2 -> location 0 -> location 1.

The first row tells us how much it will cost to get from location 0 to location 0 (remain in the same location, costs us 0), 0 to location 1 (costs us 9) and 0 to location 2 (costs us 1). The second and third rows follow the same pattern.

Comment: "At every location p that we visit, we must of already visited all locations less than p, or none at all" apart from the grammar, what exactly do you mean by "locations less than p"?

Comment: This sounds like your own description of some homework problem. What have you tried yourself? What exactly is the problem you're facing? Please share your work and ask a more specific question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: I am completely stuck here. Locations correspond to rows in our costs array. Like in the example, the first row (costs[0]) corresponds to the first location, the second row to the second location and so on. We also have 3 locations because we have 3 rows and for example, costs[0][1] tells us the cost of going from location 0 to location 1. All the costs are in the costs array.

Comment: I added more description in the question. Let me know if anything else is not clear.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on the problem, but I think [scipy's `dijkstra`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.dijkstra.html) routine may be helpful here.

Comment: What do you mean, `if row a is bigger than row b in the costs array`? How do you compare two rows?

Comment: How does your example go from 0 to 1, if it states "we must have already visited all locations less than p, or none at all.". The second part is not true because we started at 2 (so we've already visited one location), but 1 is not less than 0, so the first half of that sentence is also not true. That seems to contradict your example.

Comment: At location 2 we still have not visited any locations smaller than 2. At location 1 we did not visit any location smaller than 1 and at location 0 we did not visit any locations smaller than 0 so the condition isn't violated at any point

Comment: I think I get it, the grammar was tripping me up. Should that be `In order to visit the location numbered 'a', either: 1. We have visited all locations x < a or 2. a is smaller than all previous locations, or both.` If so, that means all possible trajectories are: An arbitrary decreasing sequence of indices ending at 0, followed by a consecutive increasing list of all unvisited indices

Comment: @kcsquared Yes that is exactly what I meant. Sorry for my English

Comment: Feel this problem should be rewritten to be understood. After reading for 10 min. still not sure what's asking?!  A picture may be helpful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirements on which locations you can visit mean that after you start at some location `i`, you're forced to move to a lower location repeatedly until you're at location 0. At that point, you have to ascend consecutively through all the locations that are unvisited. The dynamic programming solution is not obvious, but with a fairly complex implementation you can get an `O(n^3)` DP algorithm with standard techniques.

It turns out there's an `O(n^2)` solution as well, which is optimal. It also uses `O(n)` extra space, which is maybe also optimal. The solution comes from thinking about the structure of our visits: there's a downward sequence of indices (possibly with gaps) ending at 0, and then an upward sequence starting at 0 that contains all other indices. There's `2^n` possible subsequences though, so we'll have to think more to speed this up.

---

**Two Sequences**

Suppose we have `i` locations, `0, 1, ... i-1`, and we've partitioned these into two ordered subsequences (except 0, which is at the start of both). We'll call these two sequences **U** and **D**, for up and down. Exactly one of them has to end on `i-1`. Without loss of generality, assume **U** ends with `i-1` and **D** ends with `j >= 0`.

What happens when we add a location `i`? We either add it to the end of **U** so our sequences end on `i` and `j`, or we add it to the end of **D** so our sequences end on `i-1` and `i`. If we add it to **U**, the path-sum of **U** (which we define as the sum of `cost[u][v]` for all adjacent indices `u,v` in **U**) increases by `cost[i-1][i]`. If we add the location to the end of **D**, the path-sum of **D** increases by `cost[i][j]` (since it's a downward sequence, we've flipped the indices relative to **U**).

It turns out that we only need to track the endpoints of our subsequences as we grow them, as well as the maximum combined path-sum for any pair of subsequences with those endpoints. If we let `(i, j)` denote the state where **U** ends with `i` and **D** ends with `j`, we can think about how we could have arrived here.

For example, at `(8,5)`, our previous state *must* have had a subsequence containing `7`, so our previous state must have been `(7,5)`. Therefore `max-value(8,5) = max-value(7,5) + cost[7][8]`. We always have exactly one predecessor state when the two endpoints differ by more than one.

Now consider the state `(8,7)`. We can't have come from `(7,7)`, since the only number allowed to be in both sequences is `0`. So we could have come from any of `(0,7), (1,7), ... (6,7)`: we can choose whichever will maximize our path sum.

```py
def solve(costs: List[List[int]]) -> int:
    n = len(costs)
    # Deal with edge cases
    if n == 1:
        return 0
    if n == 2:
        return max(costs[0][1], costs[1][0])

    ups = [costs[0][1]]
    downs = [costs[1][0]]

    # After iteration i, ups[j] denotes the max-value of state (i, j)
    # and downs[j] denotes the max-value of state (j, i)
    for i in range(2, n):
        ups.append(max(downs[j] + costs[j][i] for j in range(i - 1)))
        downs.append(max(ups[j] + costs[i][j] for j in range(i - 1)))

        up_gain   = costs[i-1][i]
        down_gain = costs[i][i-1]

        for j in range(i - 1):
            ups[j]   += up_gain
            downs[j] += down_gain

    return max(max(ups), max(downs))
```